# If I'm given a potential, how do I determine its frequency?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Let's say I'm given a potential $U(x)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}\left ((\frac{x}{a})^2 +(\frac{a}{x})^2\right )$ and that I need to find the frequency associated with it. I'm given that the particle of mass $m$ moves in one dimension. How would I do this?

**My attempt:**

Since this is just a simple oscillating motion problem, I took a look at Taylor's *Classical Mechanics* and reviewed its section on such motion. I saw that he did

$$F=ma=-kx$$
$$a=-\frac{k}{m}x=-w^2x \quad ; \quad w=\sqrt{k/m}$$

He called $w$ the "angular frequency" with which the cart (in his example) moves. Is this the frequency I'm looking for? If it is, how do I find it, given the potential above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ordinary" frequency is $\omega/(2\pi)$. That is, the frequency of oscillation of a harmonic oscillator with mass $m$ and stiffness constant $k$ is $\frac{k^{1/2}}{2 \pi m^{1/2}}$.

To understand the frequency of small-amplitude oscillations about the minimum of your given potential, first find its minimum. Take the second derivative of the potential at this minimum. This will correspond to $k$ in the harmonic oscillator. Nonlinear effects of course mean that the *real* frequency is not exactly the one given by this linearization; but these effects become less and less significant as you send the amplitude of the oscillation to zero.

It will turn out that this frequency is (up to a multiplicative dependence on a dimensionless function of the amplitude) the only way to combine $\epsilon,a,m$ to get the units of frequency. Hence how you could also do this using dimensional analysis.

But that just boils down to figuring out the units of $\epsilon,a,m$, which I guess are energy, length, and mass, and choosing powers of them that give you units of frequency. That's routine: energy is $M L^2 T^{-2}$, length is of course $L$, mass is of course $M$. So you want $\epsilon^{k_1} a^{k_2} m^{k_3}$ where $k_1+k_3=0,2k_1+k_2=0,-2k_1=-1$.

Comment: Why is the 2nd derivative of the potential at the minimum the $k$ value that I'm looking for? ....Ohhh wait is it because if $F=-kx$ and $F=dU/dx$, then $dF=-k=d^2U/dx^2$??

Comment: @whatwhatwhat It's analogous to that, yes.

Comment: When you set up $\epsilon^{k_1} a^{k_2}m^{k_3}$, how did you come to the conclusion that those are the only things that define the frequency?

Comment: I see where the $m$ comes from, of course, but how did you conclude, without actually calculating the 2nd derivative of $U$, that $k$ will depend on both $\epsilon$ and $a$?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat They aren't. But a basic theorem in dimensional analysis (I think it has a name, but I forget what it is) says that in a given physical system, a given quantity with units is given by any one quantity with those units times a (possibly nonlinear) function of dimensionless quantities appearing in the problem. As for your followup question, I actually don't know that, because one of the $k_i$ could be zero. It turns out that it isn't, though.

Comment: (That isn't hard to see: you need to get time, but that's only in energy, and then you have to use $a$ and $m$ to cancel the length and mass units from the energy).

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused on one small part. The question says to find the dependence of the frequency on those variables and then the next question says to find the frequency about the minimum by direct calculation. I think I understand how to do the direct calculation, but I'm not sure how I would justify that just because energy has units of $ML^2T^{-2}$, then we say $e^{k_1}a^{k_2}m^{k_3}$. There's a bit of a leap there that I'm not getting. Frequency has units of $1/T$, so why did the units of energy come up?

Comment: If you only have the three dimensional quantities $\epsilon,a,m$ to use to build other dimensional quantities, then by the theorem I said before, any dimensional quantity is of the form $\epsilon^{k_1} a^{k_2} m^{k_3}$ times some function only of the dimensionless parameters. The units of energy come into play in selecting $k_1,k_2,k_3$. Now of course you might have other quantities available, for example the amplitude, but it sounds like you're being told not to use those.

Comment: Ok this is how I would summarize all of this. If you see something wrong, please tell me because what's most important is that I understand this.

$w=\sqrt{k/m}=$ frequency, with units of $1/T^2$. $k$ depends on $\epsilon$ and $a$, so we can set up a general equation that says $\epsilon ^{k_1}a^{k_2}m^{k_3}$. This equation must result in the same units. The individual units of $\epsilon$ and $a$ are $ML^2T^{-2}$ and $L$, respectively. Then, if we let $k_1=1$, $k_2=-2$, and $k_3=-1$, we get units of $1/T^2$. The square root in $w=\sqrt{k/m}$ cancels the power of 2, so we are left with $1/T$.

Comment: I think I misspoke slightly; the whole thing $\sqrt{k/m}$ should have units of frequency. Thus the "natural" frequency should be $\epsilon^{1/2} a^{-1} m^{-1/2}$.

Comment: It was probably me that misunderstood you! Thank you so much for your help!! I get it now!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is not much well posed. I suppose that you are required to find the frequency of small oscillations around the minimum of $U(x)$, because in other positions the particle would make ample oscillations subject to a force that is not linear.
Once you found the minimum, then around that you should be able to develop $F=dU/dx=kx+O(x^2)$. And once you have found the value of $k$ then everything goes as you know.

Comment: The exact phrasing of the question is " using dimensional analysis, determine the dependence of the frequency of small oscillations
on the parameters ϵ, a, and m, to within a multiplicative dimensionless constant". I figured that if I could first find out how the frequency is related to the potential energy, then the dimensional analysis part would be easy.